# send and receive string and file over socket with streams

Tags: android, sockets, stream

I have an app that communicates on the local network through the socket with other devices. In that I also want to transfer the file and the text.
My problem is that I do not know how to get the both file and text and manage them in receive !

this is my text reciever :

```
 try {
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputstream_external = outputStream;
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            log("success to set streams");
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            log("Error: Connection is not stable, exit");
            shutdown();
        }
        while (true) {
            String message = null;
            try {
                message = inputStream.readLine();
                if (message == null) {
                    return;
                }
                G.log(message);
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
                String command = object.getString(Command.COMMAND);
                G.log(message);
```

this is my text sender:

```
public void sendCommand(String command) {
        G.log("send command + " + command);
        command = command.replace("\n", " ") + "\n";
        if (outputStream == null) {
            return;
        }
        final String commend = command;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    outputStream.write(commend.getBytes());
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    G.log("sendCommand into catch");
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }
```

how can i receive text and file together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why there are so many application level network protocols, like HTTP, FTP, SMTP.

In your case, you need two types of messages, one is string, another is file. Each message should comply to a predefined format. For example,

**[4 bytes message type] + [4 bytes message length] + [message content]**

You construct message on sender side, and parse message on receiver side.

However, in most cases, you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Search on the internet to find if there is any existing protocol suitable for you.

Comment: Tnx  , how do i construct  this format with streams and  receive that ?? can you give me explain with sample code ?

Comment: Just found several good tutorials, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html and http://crunchify.com/java-nio-non-blocking-io-with-server-client-example-java-nio-bytebuffer-and-channels-selector-java-nio-vs-io/